# Why did Captain America give Nick Fury a ten dollar bill?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

When Captain America walks onto the bridge of the ship, he gives Nick Fury a ten dollar bill. Is this because he is amazed by the ship or is it some reference to the fact that he is from a time when African Americans weren't quite treated as equals yet?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Earlier, when Nick Fury meets Captain America at the gym, they have the following conversation.

> **FURY:** He’s called Loki. He’s - not from around here. There’s a lot we’ll
> have to bring you up to speed on if you’re in. The world has gotten even stranger than you already know.
>
> **STEVE** At this point I doubt anything would surprise me.
>
> [Steve gets up, grabs his duffel bag, and another punching bag while Fury is talking.]
>
> **FURY:** Ten bucks says you’re wrong.
>
> <sup>Source: [*The Avengers* screenplay](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/the-avengers-2012.pdf)</sup>

It turns out a camouflaged flying Helicarrier was enough to make Cap pay up.

> **FURY** (to Steve and Banner): *Gentlemen.*
>
> [Steve slips Fury the ten dollars he bet earlier, in regards to nothing being able to surprise him. (to Banner) *Doctor, thank you for coming.*

Answer (score 61):

Captain America pays Nick fury $10 in response to the bet he made with him in the gym about not likely going to be amazed by anything else he was shown.

Answer (score 5):

Nick Fury bet Captain America that things would get stranger. Cap responded that things could not get stranger and boy was he wrong.

Comment: welcome to movies stack, i know being a new user don't have comment privileges, if you want to participate in question and answer you can start off ensuring you post an answer which is more descriptive than the earlier accepted answers.

Comment: I gave a simple answer to a simple question. Not much to be descriptive about. The answer could not be more obvious.

Comment: if thats the case you should now there is an even simpler accepted answer earlier to that, like i said post something unless you think your answer is much better than previous answer in some way.